# Prevent animation during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do an animation, everything works fine but I can't seem to prevent user from clicking during the animation and breaking the page layout.
I have managed to stop user when the divs are moving but I can't prevent when one div is expanded.

This is my fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/p2fo4ek0/18/

```
<div class="internet_wrap">
    <div class="internet tel" id="off_wrap">
        <div class="package" id="one">
            <div class="inner_package">
                <div class="title">title</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="package" id="two">
          <div class="inner_package">
                <div class="title">title</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="package" id="three">
           <div class="inner_package">
                <div class="title">title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var animating = false;

var clickedDiv, prevDiv, distance;

$('#off_wrap').on('click', '.package', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(animating == false) {
    animating = true;
            clickedDiv = $(this).closest('.package'),
            prevDiv = $("#off_wrap > :first-child"),
            distance = clickedDiv.offset().left - prevDiv.offset().left;

        if (!clickedDiv.is(":first-child")) {

            $.when(clickedDiv.animate({
               left: -distance
            }, 2000),
            prevDiv.animate({
                left: distance
            }, 2000)).done(function () {
                prevDiv.css('left', '0px');
                clickedDiv.css('left', '0px');
                //clickedDiv.css('width', $(window).width() - (clickedDiv.offset().left * 2));
                clickedDiv.css('z-index', '10000000');
                clickedDiv.css('overflow', 'visible');
                clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").animate({width: 260}, 2000); //regullo kte

                prevDiv.insertBefore(clickedDiv);
                clickedDiv.prependTo("#off_wrap");

                animating = false;
            });

        } else {
            clickedDiv.css('z-index', '1000');
            clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('transition', 'all 2s ease-in');
            clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('width', '260px');
        }

    }
});

    $(document).click(function() {
        animating = false;
        if(animating == false) {
            clickedDiv.css('z-index', '1');
            clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('transition', 'all 2s ease-in');
            clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('width', '60px');
            animating = false;
        }
    });
```

```
.internet {
    text-align:center;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(248, 0, 140, 0.5);
    padding-bottom:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.internet .package {
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid #FFFC00;*/
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background:#fff;
    color: rgba(0, 178, 248, 1);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.inner_package {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps instead you should just [`.finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) the animation at once? Won't work on CSS animations, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've put a lot of code in already attempting to fix the issue. I'm also a little confused as to what the issue is, as your jsFiddle doesn't give me trouble with clicking during the animation. Perhaps it's only certain situations you're speaking of.

Either way, I saw this.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    animating = false;
    if(animating == false) {
        clickedDiv.css('z-index', '1');
        clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('transition', 'all 2s ease-in');
        clickedDiv.find(".inner_package").css('width', '60px');
        animating = false;
    }
});
```

That animating = false; both before the if statement and inside the if statement function seems redundant, and I suspect one of them needs to read animating = true; Let me know if that fixes your problem or not.

**UPDATE:** While I don't understand the animations themselves, I can say this. Your using animation as a control against multiple animations running. You have a statement that seems like it might be your problem.

```
if(animating == false) {
animating = true;
//do stuff
animating = false;
}
```

This may be your problem. Try getting more specific logic. like

```
if(animatingOne == false && animatingTwo == false && animatingThree == false) {
//logic to find out which animation is triggered
//turn the appropriate animation variable to true
//turn if off when done
}
```

If this doesn't work, keep playing with logic. I suspect that one variable animating is unable to accommodate the complexity of what you're doing.

Comment: The problem is when one div is expanded and when you click outside that div. During the shrink is the problem. If during the shrink of the first div you click on sec. div for ex. they try to animate both.

If I change animating false to true I cant shrink it at all. @Goose

Comment: I think you're problem is not the click during animation. Check this out. Click on the far right div, wait for the animation to end, then click on the new far right div. Wait a few seconds and you'll see some funny behavior.

Comment: Is it intended to be an animation that only runs once, or can users continue clicking and interacting with the divs?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem when clicking the divs during shrink. now the prob is that only anmiates once. check the updated fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/p2fo4ek0/25/

Comment: I think I see other problems, but I might not be understanding the problem. On that fiddle, click the middle div, then after the animation, click the middle div again. That looks like strange behavior. Is that what you're trying to fix?

Comment: Yes, I want to fix that problem.

Comment: I updated my post with a different approach to the solution. I'll also ask, is it absolutely necessary you use parent child instead of ID to identify the divs?